# Accelerate query where I sort on a unique key and another one

Tags: postgresql

As part of a query (one side of a join actually)

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (shop_id) shop_id, id, color
 FROM products
 ORDER BY shop_id, id
```

There are btree indices on shop_id and id, but for some reasons they are not used.
`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` says:

```
 ->  Unique  (cost=724198.71..742348.37 rows=360949 width=71) (actual time=179157.101..195998.646 rows=1673170 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=724198.71..733273.54 rows=3629931 width=71) (actual time=179157.095..191853.377 rows=3599644 loops=1)
             Sort Key: products.shop_id, products.id
             Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 285064kB
             ->  Seq Scan on products  (cost=0.00..328690.31 rows=3629931 width=71) (actual time=0.025..7575.905 rows=3629713 loops=1)
```

I also tried to make an multicolum btree index on both shop_id and id, but it wasn't used.. (Maybe I did it wrong and would have had to restart postgresql and everything?)

How can I accelarete this query (with an index or something?) ?

Adding an multicolumn index on all three ("CREATE INDEX products_idx ON products USING btree (shop_id, id, color);") doesn't get used.
I experimented, and if I set a LIMIT of 10000, it will be used:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..161337.91 rows=10000 width=14) (actual time=0.043..15.973 rows=10000 loops=1)
  ->  Unique  (cost=0.00..2925620.98 rows=181335 width=14) (actual time=0.042..15.249 rows=10000 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using products_idx on products  (cost=0.00..2922753.69 rows=1146917 width=14) (actual time=0.041..12.927 rows=14004 loops=1)
Total runtime: 16.293 ms
```

There are around 3*10^6 entries (3 million)

For larger LIMIT, it uses sequential scan again :(

```
Limit  (cost=213533.52..215114.73 rows=50000 width=14) (actual time=816.580..835.075 rows=50000 loops=1)
  ->  Unique  (cost=213533.52..219268.11 rows=181335 width=14) (actual time=816.578..831.963 rows=50000 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=213533.52..216400.81 rows=1146917 width=14) (actual time=816.576..823.034 rows=80830 loops=1)
              Sort Key: shop_id, id
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 107455kB
              ->  Seq Scan on products  (cost=0.00..98100.17 rows=1146917 width=14) (actual time=0.019..296.867 rows=1146917 loops=1)
Total runtime: 840.788 ms
```

(I also had to raise the work_mem here to 128MB, otherwise there would be an external merge which takes even longer)

Comment: Did you try an index on `(shop_id, id, color)` then Postgres might do an index only scan. Plus your sort is done on disk, if you increase `work_mem` for this query so that it happens in memory, this would speed up things as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried it, but for some reason it is still not using the index